# SQL Server Aggregates and Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

having a problem with a SQL query and can't seem to figure it out. Pretty sure I'm going about it all wrong.

Basically, I have PRVDR_NUM and ITM_VAL. I Want to sum up the related ITM_VALS so each PRVDR_NUM just has one "summed up" ITM_VAL [SumReimb is the alias].

PRVDR_NUM is actually in another table; I related to it using an inner join of RPT_REC_NUM, which is in both tables.

Here's a very not working example.

```
SELECT  PRVDR_NUM,SUM(ITM_VAL) as SumReimb FROM hha2011num
INNER JOIN hha2011rpt ON hha2011num.RPT_REC_NUM = hha2011rpt.RPT_REC_NUM 
WHERE (WKSHT_CD='D000000' AND LINE_NUM = '01201') AND (CLMN_NUM='0100' OR CLMN_NUM='0200')

GROUP BY PRVDR_NUM,ITM_VAL ORDER BY ITM_VAL
```

The main thing I'm summing is CLMN_NUM 0100 and 0200, each have a different item value and I want to add them up and then group by the PRVDR_NUM.

Any suggestions?

Main problems I'm having in SQL is GROUP, Aggregates, and Calculated fields. I'm not sure how to... tie it all together. I started learning SQL about two days ago.

EDIT BELOW THIS LINE------------

Here's two different but should be the same queries.

```
SELECT  RPT_REC_NUM,SUM(ITM_VAL) SumReimb FROM hha2011num
WHERE (WKSHT_CD='D000000' AND LINE_NUM = '01201') AND CLMN_NUM in('0100','0200')

GROUP BY RPT_REC_NUM ORDER BY SumReimb

SELECT  PRVDR_NUM,SUM(ITM_VAL) as SumReimb FROM hha2011num
INNER JOIN hha2011rpt ON hha2011num.RPT_REC_NUM = hha2011rpt.RPT_REC_NUM 
WHERE WKSHT_CD='D000000' AND LINE_NUM = '01201' AND CLMN_NUM in('0100','0200')
GROUP BY PRVDR_NUM ORDER BY SumReimb
```

Now; most of the data between them IS the same, except one has 39 more entries than the other [Top one does]. Which is probably why just a handful of the data in the second one are orders of magnitude higher than I expect.

Comment: Why are you grouping and ordering by ITM_VAL? You can't group by something you're summing, and you can't order by it either. Did you mean `GROUP BY PRVDR_NUM ORDER BY SumReimb;` or `GROUP BY PRVDR_NUM ORDER BY SumReimb DESC;`? As an aside, please smack the person who named these columns.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Dollars to donuts and ex-mainframe programmer named these columns lol

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hello Medicare/Medicaid cost reports. You can have as much fun as I am right now at cms.gov :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  PRVDR_NUM,SUM(ITM_VAL) as SumReimb FROM hha2011num
INNER JOIN hha2011rpt ON hha2011num.RPT_REC_NUM = hha2011rpt.RPT_REC_NUM 
WHERE WKSHT_CD='D000000' AND LINE_NUM = '01201' AND CLMN_NUM in('0100','0200')
GROUP BY PRVDR_NUM ORDER BY PRVDR_NUM
```

Please remove ITM_VAL from the group by and order by clause. Also, I've made one small change in the where clause, instead of using or for checking the value of column CLMN_NUM, you can use "IN"

Comment: I've used that in the past, and I'm getting data that's wayyy to high.

Comment: @user1741874 then show sample data and the results you *expect*.

Comment: If the results are too high, it's because your `JOIN` criteria is incomplete, resulting in a cartesian product, the answer above is as correct as can be expected given the question.  Try `SELECT *` and remove the `GROUP BY` above to find out where your `JOIN` is insufficient.

Comment: @GOAT CO: What do you mean by insufficient? All I'm trying to do with this join is have PRVDR_NUM show up rather than RPT_REC_NUM.  [Should be one to one]

Comment: I mean that if it's resulting in a cartesian product, it's not 1:1, your `WHERE` criteria could also be wrong and not limiting as you expected, without seeing data it's hard to tell though.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to scrub data and show you what's up. Got to worry about HIPA though so it'll take some time.

Comment: I've added a two queries, it's def my inner join and group by. I haven't used "HAVING" clause before, would that be a solution?

Comment: If its your join then try to figure out the combination of columns which have one to one relationship in both the tables. If you don't have any other column except RPT_REC_NUM and its having multiple rows in other table, then right a separate query selecting distinct rows with columns RPT_REC_NUM and PRVDR_NUM and then join it with the main table.

Comment: Try this:  
with rpt_cte(PRVDR_NUM, RPT_REC_NUM) as(
select distinct PRVDR_NUM, RPT_REC_NUM from hha2011rpt)

SELECT  PRVDR_NUM,SUM(ITM_VAL) as SumReimb FROM hha2011num A
JOIN rpt_cte B ON A.RPT_REC_NUM = B.RPT_REC_NUM 
WHERE WKSHT_CD='D000000' AND LINE_NUM = '01201' AND CLMN_NUM in('0100','0200')
GROUP BY PRVDR_NUM

Comment: Its called CTE, we can use it as a temporary table.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35940/discussion-between-user1741874-and-sonam)